# Azure Data Factory - Load XML Source into SQL Sink - Nested Attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, azure-data-factory

After a good few months of manually processing some weekly XML files, I want to automate the process in Data Factory. The files are medical abstracts/journals along with any associated images

The current process is in two parts - load the details of the abstract into a details type table, then the images with the associated abstractid into a separate table

Abstract details works fine in Data Factory - where I have taken the original process:

```
DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

SELECT *
INTO Abstracts

FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Jrnl-OR-COnf/Abstract', 2)
WITH (
        [AbstractID] [int],
        [SourceID] [int],
        [AbstractNum] [nvarchar](50),
        [AbstractType] [varchar](50),
        [Jrnl-OR-ConfID] [int],
        [Source] [nvarchar](20),
        [Jrnl-OR-ConfName] [nvarchar](500) ,
        [TitleAbbreviation] [varchar](512),
        [Location] [nvarchar](256),
        [PubPresDate] [date],
        [AddedDate] [date],
        [ISSN] [nvarchar](25),
        [AbstractTitle] [nvarchar](1024),
        [AbstractText] [nvarchar](max),
        [Authors] [nvarchar](max),
        [Affiliations] [nvarchar](max),
        [URL] [nvarchar](300)
)
```

And added this to a Copy activity

[image: ADF1]

However - the second process for Images is not processing correctly, as ADF doesn't seem to iterate the array of attributes correctly for each image, with a bit of tinkering, I have tried using the 'Collection Reference at Abstract level on/off and don't get the required results

This is how it was working fine in SQL

```
SELECT *
INTO AbstractImages

FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/Jrnl-OR-COnf/Abstract/Images/Image', 2)
WITH (
        [AbstractID] [int] '../../AbstractID',          --Element
        [ImageData] [varbinary](max),                   --Element
        [imgID] [smallint] '@imgID'                     --Attribute
        )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

And my attempts in ADF:

[image: ADF2]

So I am not quite sure what I can do to ensure ADF iterates the array of image Attributes linked to a higher level object for each Abstract ID...

It may well just be my Implementation not following the correct equivalent of '../../AbstractID'

All I end up with is the AbstractId Element and no ImgData or imgID

Comment: Please try Mapping: Collection reference: choose Abstract array.

Comment: @LeonYue - Unfortunately, this only returns the first Image for each abstract, not subsequent images based on the [imgID], which can be up to 16 images. Looks like the [image] object is not showing as an array?

Comment: yeah, that's the limit. Data Factory still can't work well with complex(nested) format file. I'm afraid we can't achieve that.